# Linux screen command automation

Tags: bash, shell, automation

I am using the Linux `screen` command to run different directory files one by one. I have 33 VM folders, and each folder contains images to execute.

```
Root directory      = /home/root/
VM folder available = /home/root/vm1,vm2,vm3...vm32
```

I have to run all VMs at the same time. For that reason I am using the `screen` command. Each `screen` command will execute on VM. It should traverse all 33 VM folders and execute all 33 VM images at the same time.

```
Ctrl + A, C = new screen
```

Following is my code:

```
     for (( i=0; i<=33; i++))
        do
        screen
        ls
        vm1 vm2 vm3 vm4 ....vm33
        cd vm1
        ls
        qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel image -hda core-image-full-cmdline-qemux86-64.ext3 -smp 4 -m 512 -nographic --append \
    "root=/dev/hda console=ttyS0 rw mem=512M oprofile.timer=1"
        cd ..
        screen
        qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel image -hda core-image-full-cmdline-qemux86-64.ext3 -smp 4 -m 512 -nographic --append \
"root=/dev/hda console=ttyS0 rw mem=512M oprofile.timer=1"
        cd ..
        .
        .
        .
        done
```

[QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) exits as soon as it is launched, and `screen` with it. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does `qemu --execute` return immediately or does it stay running? Why are you trying to loop 33 times but operate on each vm in each loop? Are you trying to run 33 screen sessions or have 33 windows in a single screen session?

Comment: @Etan : Am trying to bring up 33 vm windows in a single screen session. But see screen ls;screen ls;screen ls; will execute and termintae :(

Comment: So don't run `ls` as the command in the screen window, run `screen qemu --execute vm#` instead to keep the window around as long as qemu is alive.

Comment: This should solve your problem:-

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47271/prevent-gnu-screen-from-terminating-session-once-executed-script-ends

Comment: This should solve your problem:-

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47271/prevent-gnu-screen-from-terminating-session-once-executed-script-ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution. Thanks to user2053215 - *https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47271/prevent-gnu-screen-from-terminating-session-once-executed-script-ends*

1. Create a shell script for executing QEMU name as "vm.sh"

   ```
   cd $1
   qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel image -hda core-image-full-cmdline-qemux86-64.ext3 -smp 4 -m 512 -nographic --append \ "root=/dev/hda console=ttyS0 rw mem=512M oprofile.timer=1
   ```
2. Then we have to create another shell script, that is, the main script:

   for (( i=1; i<=32; i++ ))
   do
     cd vm$i
       screen -dmS vm$i sh -c "./vm.sh vm${i}; exec bash"
       cd ..
   done
3. Now do a `screen -ls`. It will display all detached screens with PIDs.
4. Do "`screen -r pid` "

Done :) Special thanks go to **user2053215** and **pietro**.

Answer (score 5):

When screen is launched without parameters, the result is that an interactive screen session is opened.

One way to achieve what you want is (assuming that the current working directory is the one containing all the VM folders):

```
for (( i=1; i<=33; i++ ))
do
   cd vm${i}
   screen -dmS vm${i} qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel image -hda core-image-full-cmdline-qemux86-64.ext3 -smp 4 -m 512 -nographic --append "root=/dev/hda console=ttyS0 rw mem=512M oprofile.timer=1"
   cd ..
done
```

And here is the explanation:

For all your 33 virtual machines, enter the VM folder, and then launch a detached screen named "vmX" that keeps QEMU running.

After that, you may enter each screen by calling:

```
screen -r vmX
```

where X is the number of the virtual machine to control (e.g. kill with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> qemu or see its stdout/stderr output).

Example:

```
screen -r vm1
```

Comment: Thnaks Pietro, But am getting following message after run screen -r vm1 or scrren -r vm2 --- There is no screen to be resumed matching vm1 :(

Comment: Are you able to find the "screen"s if you search in the active processes list? ps -ef | grep -i screen .. if you are not, maybe the qemu exits as soon as it is launched, and screen with it

Comment: ... or, I copied the qemu command but i didn't note the triple '-'. Maybe there are needed just 2: qemu --execute vm${i}

Comment: with a small example i tried " screen -dmS vm1 ls vm1" then am trying to reattach " screen -r vm1" But it saying there is no matching screen to be resumed. So again i tried with "screen -dms vm1 " screen -r vm1 ----see here am able to get screen back...So its clear that if we execute some commands "ls" anything then we can not re-attach the screen.

Comment: :) qemu is just a sample i given you can use "ls" ..no need of ---execute command.

Comment: when you launch "screen -dmS vm1 ls vm1", screen exits as soon as the ls command exits. Otherwise, if you call "screen -dmS vm1" you are creating an interactive screen that stays on until you send "exit". As an example try this: for (( i=1; i<=33; i++)) ; do screen -dmS vm$i sleep 10;done. You will find 33 SCREEN and 33 sleeps in ps for the next 10 seconds.

Comment: Yes, true it stay 10 second but if i run my qemu command it will exit, is there no other way to stay alive the qemu window?

Comment: Maybe qemu is not able to run in a screen session.. have you already tried to run a vm "by hand" in a interactive screen session?